# TextTransfer type resolve issue

Tags: java

I am trying out this [code](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do;jsessionid=8E8A62BBC50652649245BFD32735A71E?Id=82) from javapractices dot com and Im seeing a type resolve issue :

```
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.ClipboardOwner;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.*;

public final class JP_Clipboard implements ClipboardOwner {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String... aArgs) {
        TextTransfer textTransfer = new TextTransfer();  <- ERROR

            // Do other stuff

    }
```

I see the following error. How do I resolve this? Im using Eclipse with Java 1.7.0_45

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    TextTransfer cannot be resolved to a type
    TextTransfer cannot be resolved to a type

    at JP_Clipboard.main(JP_Clipboard.java:20)
```

Comment: import .....? Assuming there is a class called TextTransfer.

Comment: What is TextTransfer? Where is it defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your reference.. You have renamed the **TextTransfer** class by **JP_Clipboard** in your case

So your code should be:

```
public final class JP_Clipboard implements ClipboardOwner {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String... aArgs) {
        JP_Clipboard textTransfer = new JP_Clipboard(); 



    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In the example the class name is called `TextTransfer`. You have renamed it to `JP_Clipboard`. Either use

```
JP_Clipboard textTransfer = new JP_Clipboard();
```

or rename the class back to `TextTransfer` (preferrable - follows Java naming conventions)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your example Class name **JP_Clipboard** - this should be renamed to **TextTransfer**; referring to link you have provided in your post.

Answer (score 0):

You need import for TextTransfer or it must be in same package.